# Unable to RDP onto a VM hosted on another LAN computer

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7 Pro laptop and would like to connect remotely via RDP to a guest Linux VM that is hosted on a Windows 8.1 Home edition PC.  Both machines are on my home LAN.

I'm using VirtualBox and have guest additions installed on the Linux VM.  I have enabled the remote connections via VirtualBox on port 3389 and can connect from the host OS to the guest OS via RDP to the VirtualBox host only network Ethernet adapter on IP address 192.168.56.1.

So I know that remote connections are enabled on the guest OS.  However the host only adapter is like it says, host only, so I cannot connect to it using my laptop.  I've tried connecting to the host OS's IP address and the guest OS's IP address and both fail.

I think the issue is that Windows 8.1 home edition only supports RDP client and not RDP server (so it won't accept RDP connections from other machines).  I don't want to pay the £99 to upgrade to Windows Pro just to enable 1 feature, which I'm not even sure would fix the problem in the first place.

Are there any workarounds to allow the guest OS to bypass the host OS' block on remote connections?  Or is this even the cause of the issue?  Am I totally missing the point?  Please help...

Comment: I think your issue is more that Windows cannot RDP to unix natively, only to other Windows machines, you need the protocol installed on the nix machine or use VNC instead - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/3934/is-it-possible-to-use-remote-desktop-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu Alternatively, RDP to the Win machine, then run the VM inside that, 'live'.

Answer (score 2):

use Bridge mode in the network adapters

from [Virtual Box Networking Modes](http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.co.ke/2012/06/how-to-virtualbox-networking-part-two.html)
*Bridged Adapter

`Under the Bridged Adapter, your virtual machines behave as any other computer on the network where the hosting system resides; it bridges the virtual and physical networks. The outside world can directly communicate with the guest machine.*`

Using Bridged mode allows the guest OS to connect directly to the network. therefore the guest OS gets a different IP address independent to the Host OS.

Connection via RDP using the IP address of the Guest OS.

p/s:
using port forwarding may also work. haven't used it though